How to let SwiftUI View know that ViewModel's computed property has changed?
Imagine you have ViewModel which computed property may change from time to time:
import Foundation

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var val = 42;
    
    var compProp: Int {
        return val
    }

    func maybeChange() {
        if (Int.random(in: 0..<2) == 1) {
            val += 1
            ???
            //heyViewThePropertyIsChanged(nameof(compProp))
        }
    }
}

How can I force the View:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(viewModel.compProp)").font(.title)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 320)
        .toolbar {
            Button(action: viewModel.maybeChange) {
                Label("Maybe", systemImage: "gear.badge.questionmark")
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}

to reflect such a change?

Note, your class ViewModel: ObservableObject does not @Published anything, so it will not observe any change.
Have a look at this Apple link Monitoring data it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app. Note also, in your ContentView you should have @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()  or @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

Yeah, but we cannot apply @Published macro to a computed property, can we?

Each ObservableObject offers a publisher via objectWillChange for this purpose.
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var val = 42;
    
    var compProp: Int {
        return val
    }

    func maybeChange() {
        if (Int.random(in: 0..<2) == 1) {
            objectWillChange.send()
            val += 1
        }
    }
}

This recreates the same behavior that you get with a Published property wrapper.
I'll anticipate the question of why “willChange” and not “didChange”:
Data Essentials in SwiftUI

Yeah, it did the trick.. while seems forces the view to re-observe all class properties. But for now it's OK. Thank you very much.

As described, using the objectWillChange publisher is the same as using the Published property wrapper. It is a general disadvantage of using an ObservableObject model that SwiftUI does not know which property has changed. This only became possible with the new Observable macro.

Also just found that Migrating from the Observable Object protocol to the Observable macro gives the same effect as objectWillChange.send():
import Foundation

@Observable class ViewModel {
    private var val = 42;

    var compProp: Int {
        return val
    }
    
    func maybeChange() {
        if (Int.random(in: 0..<2) == 1) {
            val += 1
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(viewModel.compProp)").font(.title)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 320)
        .toolbar {
            Button(action: viewModel.maybeChange) {
                Label("Maybe", systemImage: "gear.badge.questionmark")
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}


Note that the Observable macro is only available for iOS 17+
This means that you're giving up support for iOS 16 and older versions.
